# How to have an input of letters and change them to uppercase and lower case? JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop

I want the input to be any amount of letters in a word, so that I can have them jumbled as below. I am not sure as to how I can have any amount of letters an they can all be changed to .uppercase and .lowercase please help. I just started java a month ago and i dont understand the for and while function. Please Help me.
The output when not using 7 letters is 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at TempCheck.main(TempCheck.java:16)
When the input is"four"

```
import java.util.*;
public class ShoutAndWhisper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Now, give me a seven letter word: ");
        String word2 = kb.nextLine();
        word2 =word2.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("I shout "+word2.toUpperCase()+ " when I’m excited, but I whisper "+ word2.toLowerCase() + " when I can't disturb the neighbours!");

        char e1 = word2.charAt(0);
        char e2 = word2.charAt(1);
        char e3 = word2.charAt(2);
        char e4 = word2.charAt(3);
        char e5 = word2.charAt(4);
        char e6 = word2.charAt(5);
        char e7 = word2.charAt(6);

        e1 = Character.toLowerCase(e1); 
        e2 = Character.toUpperCase(e2); 
        e3 = Character.toLowerCase(e3); 
        e4 = Character.toUpperCase(e4); 
        e5 = Character.toLowerCase(e5); 
        e6 = Character.toUpperCase(e6); 
        e7 = Character.toLowerCase(e7); 

        System.out.println("The word jumbled is: ");
        System.out.print(e1);
        System.out.print(e2);
        System.out.print(e3);
        System.out.print(e4);
        System.out.print(e5);
        System.out.print(e6);
        System.out.print(e7);

        kb.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using `e1` up to `e7` you should use an array.

Comment: If you call `.toUpperCase()` a third time, you'll get a really nice effect. Try it out :).

Comment: For explanations about basic concepts for the Java language, you should try visiting the [Java tag's info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) page. This page has links to tutorials like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) that will show you the basics of the Java language. As an example, `for` loops can be found in the Nuts and Bolts trail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Now, give me a seven letter word: ");
        String word2 = kb.nextLine();
        word2 = word2.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("I shout "+word2.toUpperCase()+ " when I’m excited, but I whisper "+ word2.toLowerCase() + " when I can't disturb the neighbours!");

        char e1;

        System.out.println("The word jumbled is: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < word2.length(); i++)
        {
            e1 = word2.charAt(i);
            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("" + Character.toUpperCase(e1));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("" + Character.toLowerCase(e1));
            }
        }

        kb.close();
    }
```

This will allow you to give any size word as input then it will loop through the word and change every other character to either lowercase or uppercase.  The % 2 is modular division so it will return the remainder.  If the number is even then it will be 0 if its odd then it will not be 0.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Can you explain this please

Comment: The string you get from the user can be accessed as an array at each element.  We want to loop through each letter of the string and change to either upper or lowercase then display.  The loop starts at 0 (the first letter) and ends at (string.length() - 1). i is incremented each loop by 1. We get the char at the position (i) and change to either upper or lowercase then display.